# How to fix .Formula value with variables in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set a formula for a cell using a variable value in VBA code. I keep getting "Error: Expected an end statement or function." error with my current trial.

This is the formula in excel:

```
=IF(ISERROR(PERCENTILE($O11:$O1067,0.2)),"",PERCENTILE(IF($O11:$O1067>0,$O11:$O1067),0.2))
```

Here is my current code:

`wsDest.Range("CA3").Formula = _ "=IF(ISERROR(PERCENTILE($O11:$O"&NewLastRow",0.2)),"""",PERCENTILE(IF($O11:$O _ "&NewLastRow">0,$O11:$O"&NewLastRow"),0.2))"`

What is wrong???

Comment: you need to put a space before and after each `&` in the formula and you need to add ` & ` after each `NewLastRow`

Comment: `"=IF(ISERROR(PERCENTILE($O11:$O" & NewLastRow & ",0.2)),"""",PERCENTILE(IF($O11:$O" & NewLastRow & ">0,$O11:$O" & NewLastRow & "),0.2))"`

Comment: You will probably also want `.FormulaArray` instead of `.Formula`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SiddarthRout :

`"=IF(ISERROR(PERCENTILE($O11:$O" & NewLastRow & ",0.2)),"""",PERCENTILE(IF($O11:$O" & NewLastRow & ">0,$O11:$O" & NewLastRow & "),0.2))"`